# mysql join 4 tables путаются ячейки в строках

Tags: mysql, sql, join

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
SELECT service.name, operator.fio AS op_fio, client.fio AS cl_fio,
MAX(done.day) FROM done
JOIN operator ON done.id_oper = operator.id
JOIN service ON done.id_serv = service.id
JOIN client ON done.id_client = client.id
GROUP BY service.name;
```

не понятно почему высвечиваются ячейки(подчеркнутые красным) имеющие связь(join) с отмеченным красным в табл "done", а не высвечиваются ячейки имеющие связь(join) с отмеченным зеленным. Как решить данную задачу, что я не правильно делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> не понятно почему высвечиваются ячейки(подчеркнутые красным)

потому operator.fio AS op_fio, client.fio AS cl_fio используются без групповых функций и по ним не делается группировка. Сервер MySQL выбирает для них случайное значение из группы. Стандартом такие запросы вообще запрещены.

Можно, например, в подзапросе выбрать Идслужбы и максимальную дату звонка, по ним уже подтягивать оператора и клиента.
Другие способы с примерами есть в этой [статье](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/18.html)

Answer (score 0):

Все правильно срабатывает.

Вы сделали `GROUP BY service.name` и получается, для одной службы для любого Оператора и Клиента будет только 1 запись.

Так как у вас стоит `MAX(done.day)` значение максимальное берется `2013.04.07`

тут нужно сам запрос поменять:

```
SELECT service.name, operator.fio AS op_fio, client.fio AS cl_fio,
MAX(done.day) FROM done
LEFT JOIN operator ON done.id_oper = operator.id
LEFT JOIN service ON done.id_serv = service.id
LEFT JOIN client ON done.id_client = client.id
GROUP BY service.name, done.id_serv, done.id_oper, done.id_client;
```

как то так, хотябы

---

**UPDATE**

Ответ на комментарий

```
SELECT service.name, operator.fio AS op_fio, client.fio AS cl_fio, 
FROM done
INNER JOIN (SELECT id_serv, MAX(day) AS MaxDay
      FROM done
      GROUP BY id_serv) groupedDone
      ON done.id_serv = groupedDone.id_serv
      AND done.day= groupedDone.MaxDay
LEFT JOIN operator ON done.id_oper = operator.id
LEFT JOIN service ON done.id_serv = service.id
LEFT JOIN client ON done.id_client = client.id;
```

Comment: нам нужно получить имя службы дату когда она последний раз работала, с каким клинтом и оператором она последний раз работала, и так для каждой службы. Служб у нас 4 - определенных в 1 табл и одна неизвестная. То есть должно быть всего 5 строк. по строке на службу. и вот в каждой строке эти данные

Comment: @AlexWaits значит ваш запрос правильно работает. Просто задача другая. Вы же не указали в запросе, что нужно взять того оператора у которога дата последняя по службе. Запрос просто произвольно берет любого оператора. Запрос нужно менять.

Comment: @AlexWaits Проверьте **UPDATE**

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM done INNER JOIN (SELECT id_serv, MAX(day) AS MaxDay       FROM done       G' at line 2